# Fully replace username with email Django

Tags: django

I want fully remove username in my User model and replace with email. At first i override `USERNAME_FIELD`. But if i want to use `email` not `username` i must to add `unique=True` in `email` field. After that change `UserManager` (create user using email and password). Also replace `username` occurances with `email` in `UserAdmin` and forms, attached to him.

My question is it true to override Django classes, or is there better way to use `email` and don't use `username` at all.

Comment: There is whole section explaining this in docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example

Answer (score 3):

You can replace Django User model with custom Model.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/

An extract from django docs:

> Some kinds of projects may have authentication requirements for which
>   Django’s built-in User model is not always appropriate. For instance,
>   on some sites it makes more sense to use an **email address** as your
>   identification token instead of a username.

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'
```